# No geolocation data in my photos even though location services are on for Camera

Tags: ios, camera, geolocation

It turns out none of my photos on my iPhone 4S (ios 6.1.3) are geotagged. The location services are on for camera and GPS works (confirmed in Maps for example).

I downloaded an image via image capture, and it's not geotagged when viewed in iPhoto on my Mac.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens when you look at the places view on iOS to inspect the camera roll? Can we presume that the geolocation is correct there for pictures you have taken and that the problem is once they get onto your Mac?

Comment: "I downloaded an image via image capture" -- can you clarify what you mean by this? You imported the photos in to iPhoto by connecting your iPhone and sync'ing it with iPhoto?

Comment: Hmm for some of the images I was in airplane mode! Silly. Must investigate further.